# On Sobolev space $W^{2,2}$, is the inner product of the derivative of a function and the function itself zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, inner-products

Let $\;f\in W^{2,2}(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^2)\;$, then is it always true that $\;{\langle f,f' \rangle}_{L^2}=0\;$?

I'm dealing with some integrals and I observed that in my notes the term $\;\int_{\mathbb R} (ff')'\;dx\;$ always vanishes without further explanation.

Hence I thought that the inner product $\;{\langle f,f' \rangle}_{L^2}\;$ should be zero whenever $\;f \in W^{2,2}\;$ but I can't see how to prove it.

Comment: This does not make sense, there is no sense in differentiating when all the variables are already integrated out.

Comment: @Ian It was something I didn't like in my way... still, is the answer in my question positive?

Comment: Consider the case of a one dimensional codomain and you can antidifferentiate $ f f'$. The antiderivative is $f^2/2$. Does this vanish at infinity? $L^2$ alone does not provide this.

Comment: @Ian Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking about two different integrals, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}ff'$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(ff')'$. The answer is yes for both: such integrals are zero for all $f\in W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$. (The codomain being two-dimensional does not make a difference.)

Since smooth compactly supported functions are dense in $W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$, the questions to ask are:

1. Is this integral expression zero for smooth compactly supported functions?
2. Is it continuous with respect to the $W^{2,2}$ norm?

The answer is "yes" to both, in both cases. For smooth compactly supported functions, we have an integral of the derivative of some expression (using $ff' = (f^2/2)'$), and such an integral vanishes.

For the second question, it's easier to think in terms of the bilinear form $B(f, g) = \int fg'$ or $B(f, g) = \int (fg')'$. Is this bilinear form bounded on $W^{2, 2}$, meaning $|B(f, g)|\le C\|f\|\|g\|$? Yes in both cases (using Cauchy-Schwarz): only derivatives up to order 2 are involved, and they are all controlled by the $W^{2,2}$ norm in the suitable way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply since you got me out of a big confusion here! Although I understand what you say, it's still not clear to me why the second integral expression should be zero. For example, for the first one I used the translation invariant of inner product and I concuded that $\;\frac{\partial}{\partial m} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x-m)f(x-m)\;dx=0 \Rightarrow \int_{\mathbb R} -2f(x-m)f'(x-m)\;dx=0 \Rightarrow \langle f,f' \rangle=0\;$. But I can't find a similar trick for the second one. How did you know it's zero?